# Problema con constructores C++

Tags: c++, constructor

Me salen errores con mi código diciendo: **Undefined symbol: Videos::Videos()**

El código se trata sobre una plataforma tipo NETFLIX, en la que carga  un archivo cvs y te da el nombre de las películas y series por genero y con calificación. Apenas estoy empezando con la parte de películas, pero no me deja correrlo y no encuentro de donde viene el error.  Todo corre bien menos eso, es el único error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Videos{
  private:
    string id;
    string nombre;
    int duracion;
    string genero;
    float calificacion;
    
    public:
    Videos();
    Videos(string _id, string _nombre, int _duracion, string _genero, float _calificacion){
    id = _id;
    nombre = _nombre;
    duracion = _duracion;
    genero = _genero;
    calificacion = _calificacion;
    }
    
    
    void setId(string);
    string getId();
    
    void setNombre(string);
    string getNombre();
    
    void setDuracion(int);
    int getDuracion();
    
    void setGenero(string);
    string getGenero();
    
    void setCalificacion(float);
    float getCalificacion();
    
    virtual void leer_informacion();
    virtual void mostrar_informacion();
    virtual void mostar_por_genero(string);
    //virtual void mostrar_calificacion();
};


//Clase Pelicula
class Peliculas:public Videos{
    private:
    Peliculas *arrPtrPeliculas[100];
    int cantidad_peliculas;
    public:
    Peliculas();
    Peliculas(string _id, string _nombre, int _duracion, string _genero, float _calificacion):Videos(_id, _nombre, _duracion, _genero, _calificacion){
    }
    void leer_informacion();
    void mostrar_informacion();
    void mostar_por_genero(string);

};


//Clase Serie
/*class Serie: public Videos{
    public:
    Serie();
    Serie(string _id, string _nombre, int _duracion, string _genero, float _calificacion):Videos(_id, _nombre, _duracion, _genero, _calificacion){
    }
    void mostrar_informacion();
};

//Clase Episodio
class Episodio:public Serie{
  public:
    string titulo;
    int temporada ;
    Episodio(string _id, string _titulo, int _nombre,):Videos(_id, _nombre, _duracion, _genero, _calificacion);
    titulo = _titulo;
    temporada = _temporada;
}; */



//Getters y Setter
void Videos::setId(string id){
    id = id;
}
string Videos::getId(){
    return id;
}
void Videos::setNombre(string nombre){
    nombre = nombre;
}
string Videos::getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}
void Videos::setDuracion(int duracion){
    duracion = duracion;
}
int Videos::getDuracion(){
    return duracion;
}
void Videos::setGenero(string genero){
    genero = genero;
}
string Videos::getGenero(){
    return genero;
}
void Videos::setCalificacion(float calificacion){
    calificacion = calificacion;
}
float Videos::getCalificacion(){
    return calificacion;
}

Peliculas::Peliculas(){
    cantidad_peliculas = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< 100; i++){
        arrPtrPeliculas[i]= nullptr;
    }
}

void Peliculas::leer_informacion(){
    fstream fin;
    fin.open("NETLIX_PELICULAS.cvs", ios::in);
    string row[5];
    string line, word;
    cantidad_peliculas = 0;
    while(getline(fin, line)){
        cout<<cantidad_peliculas<<line<<endl;
        stringstream s(line);
        int i = 0;
        while(getline(s,word,',')){
            row[i++]=word;
        }
        arrPtrPeliculas[cantidad_peliculas]=new Peliculas(row[0],row[1], stoi(row[2]),row[3],stoi(row[4]));
               cout<<"ID: "<<row[0]<<endl;
               cout<<"Nombre: " <<row[1]<<endl;
               cout<<"Duracion: " <<row[2]<<endl;
               cout<<"Genero: "<<row[3]<<endl;
               cout<<"Calficacion: " <<row[4]<<endl;
        
               cout <<"Dentro del objeto: ";
               arrPtrPeliculas[cantidad_peliculas]->mostrar_informacion();
               cantidad_peliculas=cantidad_peliculas+1;
               cout<<endl;
               cout<<endl;
    }
    fin.close();
}

void Peliculas::mostrar_informacion(){
    leer_informacion();
    
    cout << " ID    Nombre     Duracion     Genero      Calificacion  "<<endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_peliculas; i++){
        arrPtrPeliculas[i]->mostrar_informacion();
        
    }
    
}


void Peliculas::mostar_por_genero(string genero){
    leer_informacion();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    cout << " Id    Nombre     Duracion     Genero     Calificacion "<< endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_peliculas; i++){
        if (arrPtrPeliculas[i]->getGenero( )  == genero)
            arrPtrPeliculas[i]->mostrar_informacion();
          }
}

int main(){
    int operador;
    //do{
        cout<<"--------MENU PRINCIPAL------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Ver todos los videos"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Ver todas las peliculas"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Ver las peliculas por genro"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Ver todas las series"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. Ver las series por genero"<<endl;
        cout<<"6. Salir";
        cout<<"Seleccione una opcion: ";
        cin>>operador;
        switch(operador){
            case 1:
            {
                string a,b,d;
                int c = 0;
                float e = 0 ;
                Videos *ptrv;
                Videos v(a,b,c,d,e);
                ptrv = &v;
                ptrv -> mostrar_informacion();
            break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                string a,b,d;
                int c = 0;
                float e = 0;
                Videos *ptrp1;
                Peliculas p1(a,b,c,d,e);
                ptrp1 = &p1;
                ptrp1 -> mostrar_informacion();
            break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                string g;
                cout<<"Que genero quieres ver: "<<endl;
                cin>>g;
            Peliculas x3;
            x3.mostar_por_genero(g);
            break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                cout<<"FALTA"<<endl;
            //Serie x4;
            //x4.mostrar_informacion();
            break;
            }
            case 5:
            {
            //Serie x5;
            //x5.mostar_por_genero();
            break;
            }

        }
   // }
   // while(operator != 6);
  //  {
       // cout<<"ADIOS"<<endl;
   // }
        

    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenida a SOe. Por favor, revisa como hacer un [mcve] para poner una cantidad de código manejable en la pregunta.

Comment: Y no se te ocurrio buscar que significaba el error? No hacia falta que nos mandaras 250 lineas de codigo para entender que solo declaraste `Videos::Videos()` sin definirlo en ningun lado.

Answer (score 0):

El error es claro y conciso, tal vez no lo entiendes por estar en inglés, te lo traduzco:

> Undefined symbol: Videos::Videos()

> Símbolo no definido: Videos::Videos()

El compilador te está diciendo que no se ha definido un símbolo que estás usando, en concreto no se ha definido el constructor del objeto `Videos`:

```
//              Los cuatro puntos (::) indican que el símbolo de la derecha
//          ___ pertenece al de la izquierda
//         /
//        /
//       vv
   Videos::Videos()
// ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
//    \        \___ Constructor por defecto (sin parámetros) de Videos
//     \
//      \___ Objeto Videos
```

Lo de definir, significa que no le has dicho al compilador qué es lo que hace ese símbolo. En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) los símbolos pueden existir en dos niveles:

- **Declaración**: Le dices al compilador que un símbolo existe, pero no entras en detalles de lo que es ese símbolo, por ejemplo:

  ```
  class Videos{
    public:
    // Declaramos el constructor, ahora el compilador sabe que existe, pero no sabe qué hace
    Videos();
  }
  ```
- **Definición**: Le describes al compilador que lo que hace un símbolo, por ejemplo:

  ```
  Videos::Videos() {
    // Definimos todas las acciones que deben hacerse al construir el objeto Videos.
  }
  ```

En resumen, te falta definir el constructor, justo lo que decía el error: **Undefined symbol: Videos::Videos()**.